# Azure Service Bus Limit Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

We have the following architecture:

- When a file is inserted into the blob storage the event grid call an Azure Function
- The Azure Function read the file and insert a message into the service bus with meta information
- An App Service is processing those Service Bus messages later.

But sometimes we have too much file add events at once and we reach the limit of insertion in the service bus so we would like to limit the number of Azure Function that could be created.
Do we have a way to limit it or maybe limit the rate of the event grid trigger?

Regards,

Comment: what you mean by "reach the limit of insertion in to the service bus" ? what error are you getting ? If the number of blob storage files will be huge, then you can try to ingest into Event Hubs instead of Service bus.

Comment: Also, are you using Premium ASB or Standard?